# How can i try to figure out the encoding of a string?

Tags: encryption, decode, encode

I'm trying to decode a json and have no idea where to start.
i would like to know how i can try to figure out what encoding this json or any other string is using, how can i do that? **is there a list of the most used encoders**?
I only know a few formats:
**Base64, HEX, UTF8, URL, MD5**

Sorry for my ignorance I'm new to the subject and want to learn more.

```json
{
  "event":2,
   "data":{
       "YEAbwsMHIW-f":"A6iuU6B7AQAAUeDxaDmLyNOisr_dYVFqppbIY-iIPEOIvfBKifp72ZzGne6GAclFzmSuctWowH8AADQwAAAAAA==",
       "YEAbwsMHIW-b":"53sf37",
       "YEAbwsMHIW-c":"AGB8UaB7AQAAvAKgqnFEgnYq1px145WH3ZX9OzlLT0yTIb2g0jS6CZVAueBb",
       "YEAbwsMHIW-d":"ABaChIjBDKGNgUGAQZIQhISi0eIApJmBDgA0ugmVQLngWwAAAABVAgdIAPyLJ_H11hCM1VUTI6_DwmE",
       "YEAbwsMHIW-z":"q",
       "YEAbwsMHIW-a":"UYD3v6BpIocdXxHjH0gD8ng2eU2Nx_KWHUmYHEG3XxSo3Eewva8p9vuvaoJrOH7lhji_L10el5qvehZuMJ1sGse2QrF7JhP=KUg7XJ37ivsgUzImVIztGpZsZkDvT=Qji8=ds0sn_m4wojH6ElNQDD0ZhhgBulkbpUq0uAw7-zLzG8YDcVCsHbcpPiiUTMwrAie32C-TzEbD9EsBt=GVYJwErhx5TrxSfGcQU_WMEBBds6kE3Nm_hte7L3zvDSpqkbKDlTNtAtYZOWgMg4huh-_nAhsMx0zzQ5MNMls2-o5AbZm3RIljmTs5IO4U0bwmWzJScqhg1YCDu3GAqo96YX5NglFSoUsMx8W=TuvEngXO7eROuMQdvcWtVMWY5gcRhgXkUACdWNtrkr=J-6q8PSnNc8PdwpU2Hzw3_uJgIJ8SF7F=wS1ixSgwY-sKhlKYWPQiOGCsDjKUphWOhG6eGkBFKbi5gHmffzqXtKrn413At3A0MxvP=Mbn3FLxI9HGQ-b4A8dIMh0Z_3MsxfD3sruw1bDg_gxMoI4tmKBO-MvQrmtGBPYF1_I=RUknIwfnVQFWDS7So6gmfT4n56OWxrr2smutwE4PdmnOwczVsxRZhEKBpWEFOvp-zYjHte4fYW9gJt7Hg7tJIuTQg95jYGbabLktnX44XCOc7=dn5HKRS8BtMAb2=W4xlEDxo2cUA=pNn7OCG4lGuiUADCmULnVRCQ66L9cZwoxJEwVUdQvrwmRtpfIi_vrrwQS0l-TMknTmHItCJ3Ul68WctnvCqOcok=0_SwBVXed0KEWP7W=pR3xV92eYKRt3ou98NKCIukems6KjpMMFG-kIhn5acGUL_c7SzE=v2qNE5WvHmjvfEx8da3LSlzku8EGMKf8T_q6JZzJpPWl_KUZNz6hfATDLJTQMPI_5v9mwqstTFIzpsqYvpKMZ5WwJr9iUFWZMpV3lQKeISeHRDHF-O3g=dc6AgRIKGqlB-iY_FluUQb6JoJGU7MJvVwaaIDtGGULZ8fKG01djvNtTzv9Sf=sMnZmAeiD0ER86hKo=FxwW6ShjVKFwf=IEIpD=xELrZA0GLfxxvo22fzTLrNDnRGMU1oPeZsEEb_Ecuk_FxWVXdbLWktmPNIR3wuxegXSLwaeVI-0TaXdCEIejR1e_u0afWYaVpiFkRooM3mRituqc1GBH8dWSA9tU2o3cb0_JEv2pru2Q0rxZuEQvJiBuBscJaPGF=X3vK1mZEBlQVaeVThowDPLKIv3bpHwqCk0DScx6eq97k5JCnhAG--BUSIEUNdmbsCmG6Wu5MaVmu37MGUZtM3wsECwnAJafXDdw4YDd41tnkAUQ9sPIbNSgKfA2wCDDSAIhgfLVsYCNLnC4XVHE8CfsdBODU2tF3nKJcmT-3YwsHreXE323oD-dbWJtjBEUWGqW7nZLvQ5EnQzRhUW7gj88XN0fTtH_8H7cFSuDoMl2C=Q5VBpAHo-FrPzGHN9Rm=MA4_oJBNvPNT_SGlhIQ8M3veZn4Z3r7tba_6H3mr1ZRY4nfrove9AF67th-vLVvqsRexE8KIYTNHHvzIjTMC2eXrw9BFJvlwkaLAWj=CAO-Pq8k60Nxq_eUKAVt7r2aTpT6nbiAPS2XlhJePr2eL61WNNwZHzvwvVGC7MvpoEPIN7tO3K_mTnaKRNWD_Ee3NPnZbpl6cI=XrATTsugAXI5S3c1LNpEHrXmN3oMjB6ZhGshO4j6L0MBbR_24=ItKXzo4-QI=E-Av0g_6Z7=qwkpPQ4vlMaFvpNEvSxXU3h88Jh=AzZ3BuphHhzVdNN4D2Jih5uAarXU2eNYsCktfUKJgWfbCkK4qbMF0qonILBdArOWRf7xbg2dFor8jlZBfbhiDjmMPaLJRQwojJtT27DE_0X2indDo0MQ4WWCXbrnTaaddDQgr6684xfxnBLCbqkcdXZQW2LTESS6c-smg8Uxsw7dJn2OsrYaubQUnxVizhHeCpTxdx34tohh-m_OQcaKsMOQ6I7nr1u5vr_1_w8TKMY0jf1po9km1_QYZVrehx-UP_bGnHLiMiQFVz9VNeed_0xsHGJZN3WxZ344WATtVmCpMWURgmx0x4hnlrf4xLnQEhxA5NYGNxeAsx9jhoDkU23f=KT8hpWJzFOk1LsxGLCZCAFNRM4ILWsNtc=sbMh2ECKHUmV5gGFKmIsBSgLxUSE0=988IGdV_wiqmjSRHNZqGVam0JYg3Yw6YTtC5WYrLRSewwjSiSEkeg7gcOQsp9N1YO2uGKm4-wMC_u3GgPwYwe5Wj2J6nxBMl2w5o9a16kKW_1WLZEdP0MKReBWtX8kP_GSDmt2KoZ6MkM3ktg5fSQdMmkHJPCFIU5ipC05QX=DBO5wsnMbFPl91MU=ZGV9jvZGZJZfS9aVf0k0QaMv9XARILI=Pmlhg8vELbPGbLtJf-eDbAGmNulE_nUi6-Yrq0R78W9fOcNsiBZRhGOK3EVsG205_=0VTDiiHUkEXgD8OmA-kcBs_R0u5mnxvPZse-JMZFPf4O_WFOzLhC1_8qP=Oo9wKlXI=Yamcc_Nr6FWswWZd91XlYo9QBIVxtbcXrRRL-zs=rpYcXMNM_j50X=BhD3sNqrFwWvmzSAchUl4JnhvjN0XJRQPp5_vxJsBKbNZXZtZWhOnruqW5o0LrQCKXK4ww2vOb_5hY3srdcaDliK1liQ8gq4T1AMGcV6sHUz-S01Qz1aD5jZtEz7YBMOG6G6P_50Nu85zYv8sQ3LCUfgFbR3sSg3dRDsP=WweqTvJLg5ki95It1I8vWIHJW5H9pcNTt8AB1wV_4chtZEhiTEmWMhYS6pwb1CC-cTj50o3niWEk9BqzfV5VrX1MAaj1YYlcvZmgVtL-0jECQCjbpgDn3DfiqTX-0GcXNZLa0haEpRG4DXTu3p7Fw1MUhs5dNiRWMU2_AlhtHbcTA4iARrerobSqs_Qn9U3R_bVYTgfU60NM5n1xLxspqKDprxctmpjhL1oGLS3vRb2Vkh1TPpicWo3BY6vjihM_gs6ER6bZeDfW0Rza8ARiEfHKA23dlio0r-e6RWZj8J6-sRPYcRjOgpEPIskW5zUWfnpeOW4516DfZ1RgTRzE2vdnajGum6dzQkAeucis_eMFKvVdpkNtl7IRYGhBRcle6qjetZVkd=N6p1gZ132G-RHdSlXm0g0E24bMXkcKgx21jaK1iTDxuBUZLWvALRJUNq3uuXKL-3Nw1R6Xu6VHkow5XH4jD3gzr7ve4nOhugTD-8qBSDxdNt3IFSNOYbS9iIGc995EDkWEw8a82QwOEsq7Un-Es5Lnv4noYD7HjCX0HkxnLSMiqmdSdBePZ8kVtlBH0H8olCYJlQ-_652F_DGAIO2rl_6fY-dG6-v9iqImjRg-1wFzR6q_tk2RjkCXTFmnO_q6PBKQ0Eb4SFT77h7ri3NQ_qGUGOkjNrcI2HTnmGLlgFsuXmtbm9phahUNJG-9-TiIObSJK5zxQJDJn2tbbEserXp4acFBGYc103aO1NauerDt4ZNn1sHSQhHHTXYa7UuOERcr_DLAt1HOt_D7_ioRTozmW7vJdV3OIRm4S2SM83AMgSYw=Tzzqzc4reatgd4H_Lo=8Yx5ksBhgQFBNgEIndkek7N3U6NExsafQGx4J9JA-0HS1LD3cd4wi=QmLfLb"
    }
}
```

or

```json
{"event":2,"data":{"YEAbwsMHIW-f":"A6iuU6B7AQAAUeDxaDmLyNOisr_dYVFqppbIY-iIPEOIvfBKifp72ZzGne6GAclFzmSuctWowH8AADQwAAAAAA==","YEAbwsMHIW-b":"53sf37","YEAbwsMHIW-c":"AGB8UaB7AQAAvAKgqnFEgnYq1px145WH3ZX9OzlLT0yTIb2g0jS6CZVAueBb","YEAbwsMHIW-d":"ABaChIjBDKGNgUGAQZIQhISi0eIApJmBDgA0ugmVQLngWwAAAABVAgdIAPyLJ_H11hCM1VUTI6_DwmE","YEAbwsMHIW-z":"q","YEAbwsMHIW-a":"UYD3v6BpIocdXxHjH0gD8ng2eU2Nx_KWHUmYHEG3XxSo3Eewva8p9vuvaoJrOH7lhji_L10el5qvehZuMJ1sGse2QrF7JhP=KUg7XJ37ivsgUzImVIztGpZsZkDvT=Qji8=ds0sn_m4wojH6ElNQDD0ZhhgBulkbpUq0uAw7-zLzG8YDcVCsHbcpPiiUTMwrAie32C-TzEbD9EsBt=GVYJwErhx5TrxSfGcQU_WMEBBds6kE3Nm_hte7L3zvDSpqkbKDlTNtAtYZOWgMg4huh-_nAhsMx0zzQ5MNMls2-o5AbZm3RIljmTs5IO4U0bwmWzJScqhg1YCDu3GAqo96YX5NglFSoUsMx8W=TuvEngXO7eROuMQdvcWtVMWY5gcRhgXkUACdWNtrkr=J-6q8PSnNc8PdwpU2Hzw3_uJgIJ8SF7F=wS1ixSgwY-sKhlKYWPQiOGCsDjKUphWOhG6eGkBFKbi5gHmffzqXtKrn413At3A0MxvP=Mbn3FLxI9HGQ-b4A8dIMh0Z_3MsxfD3sruw1bDg_gxMoI4tmKBO-MvQrmtGBPYF1_I=RUknIwfnVQFWDS7So6gmfT4n56OWxrr2smutwE4PdmnOwczVsxRZhEKBpWEFOvp-zYjHte4fYW9gJt7Hg7tJIuTQg95jYGbabLktnX44XCOc7=dn5HKRS8BtMAb2=W4xlEDxo2cUA=pNn7OCG4lGuiUADCmULnVRCQ66L9cZwoxJEwVUdQvrwmRtpfIi_vrrwQS0l-TMknTmHItCJ3Ul68WctnvCqOcok=0_SwBVXed0KEWP7W=pR3xV92eYKRt3ou98NKCIukems6KjpMMFG-kIhn5acGUL_c7SzE=v2qNE5WvHmjvfEx8da3LSlzku8EGMKf8T_q6JZzJpPWl_KUZNz6hfATDLJTQMPI_5v9mwqstTFIzpsqYvpKMZ5WwJr9iUFWZMpV3lQKeISeHRDHF-O3g=dc6AgRIKGqlB-iY_FluUQb6JoJGU7MJvVwaaIDtGGULZ8fKG01djvNtTzv9Sf=sMnZmAeiD0ER86hKo=FxwW6ShjVKFwf=IEIpD=xELrZA0GLfxxvo22fzTLrNDnRGMU1oPeZsEEb_Ecuk_FxWVXdbLWktmPNIR3wuxegXSLwaeVI-0TaXdCEIejR1e_u0afWYaVpiFkRooM3mRituqc1GBH8dWSA9tU2o3cb0_JEv2pru2Q0rxZuEQvJiBuBscJaPGF=X3vK1mZEBlQVaeVThowDPLKIv3bpHwqCk0DScx6eq97k5JCnhAG--BUSIEUNdmbsCmG6Wu5MaVmu37MGUZtM3wsECwnAJafXDdw4YDd41tnkAUQ9sPIbNSgKfA2wCDDSAIhgfLVsYCNLnC4XVHE8CfsdBODU2tF3nKJcmT-3YwsHreXE323oD-dbWJtjBEUWGqW7nZLvQ5EnQzRhUW7gj88XN0fTtH_8H7cFSuDoMl2C=Q5VBpAHo-FrPzGHN9Rm=MA4_oJBNvPNT_SGlhIQ8M3veZn4Z3r7tba_6H3mr1ZRY4nfrove9AF67th-vLVvqsRexE8KIYTNHHvzIjTMC2eXrw9BFJvlwkaLAWj=CAO-Pq8k60Nxq_eUKAVt7r2aTpT6nbiAPS2XlhJePr2eL61WNNwZHzvwvVGC7MvpoEPIN7tO3K_mTnaKRNWD_Ee3NPnZbpl6cI=XrATTsugAXI5S3c1LNpEHrXmN3oMjB6ZhGshO4j6L0MBbR_24=ItKXzo4-QI=E-Av0g_6Z7=qwkpPQ4vlMaFvpNEvSxXU3h88Jh=AzZ3BuphHhzVdNN4D2Jih5uAarXU2eNYsCktfUKJgWfbCkK4qbMF0qonILBdArOWRf7xbg2dFor8jlZBfbhiDjmMPaLJRQwojJtT27DE_0X2indDo0MQ4WWCXbrnTaaddDQgr6684xfxnBLCbqkcdXZQW2LTESS6c-smg8Uxsw7dJn2OsrYaubQUnxVizhHeCpTxdx34tohh-m_OQcaKsMOQ6I7nr1u5vr_1_w8TKMY0jf1po9km1_QYZVrehx-UP_bGnHLiMiQFVz9VNeed_0xsHGJZN3WxZ344WATtVmCpMWURgmx0x4hnlrf4xLnQEhxA5NYGNxeAsx9jhoDkU23f=KT8hpWJzFOk1LsxGLCZCAFNRM4ILWsNtc=sbMh2ECKHUmV5gGFKmIsBSgLxUSE0=988IGdV_wiqmjSRHNZqGVam0JYg3Yw6YTtC5WYrLRSewwjSiSEkeg7gcOQsp9N1YO2uGKm4-wMC_u3GgPwYwe5Wj2J6nxBMl2w5o9a16kKW_1WLZEdP0MKReBWtX8kP_GSDmt2KoZ6MkM3ktg5fSQdMmkHJPCFIU5ipC05QX=DBO5wsnMbFPl91MU=ZGV9jvZGZJZfS9aVf0k0QaMv9XARILI=Pmlhg8vELbPGbLtJf-eDbAGmNulE_nUi6-Yrq0R78W9fOcNsiBZRhGOK3EVsG205_=0VTDiiHUkEXgD8OmA-kcBs_R0u5mnxvPZse-JMZFPf4O_WFOzLhC1_8qP=Oo9wKlXI=Yamcc_Nr6FWswWZd91XlYo9QBIVxtbcXrRRL-zs=rpYcXMNM_j50X=BhD3sNqrFwWvmzSAchUl4JnhvjN0XJRQPp5_vxJsBKbNZXZtZWhOnruqW5o0LrQCKXK4ww2vOb_5hY3srdcaDliK1liQ8gq4T1AMGcV6sHUz-S01Qz1aD5jZtEz7YBMOG6G6P_50Nu85zYv8sQ3LCUfgFbR3sSg3dRDsP=WweqTvJLg5ki95It1I8vWIHJW5H9pcNTt8AB1wV_4chtZEhiTEmWMhYS6pwb1CC-cTj50o3niWEk9BqzfV5VrX1MAaj1YYlcvZmgVtL-0jECQCjbpgDn3DfiqTX-0GcXNZLa0haEpRG4DXTu3p7Fw1MUhs5dNiRWMU2_AlhtHbcTA4iARrerobSqs_Qn9U3R_bVYTgfU60NM5n1xLxspqKDprxctmpjhL1oGLS3vRb2Vkh1TPpicWo3BY6vjihM_gs6ER6bZeDfW0Rza8ARiEfHKA23dlio0r-e6RWZj8J6-sRPYcRjOgpEPIskW5zUWfnpeOW4516DfZ1RgTRzE2vdnajGum6dzQkAeucis_eMFKvVdpkNtl7IRYGhBRcle6qjetZVkd=N6p1gZ132G-RHdSlXm0g0E24bMXkcKgx21jaK1iTDxuBUZLWvALRJUNq3uuXKL-3Nw1R6Xu6VHkow5XH4jD3gzr7ve4nOhugTD-8qBSDxdNt3IFSNOYbS9iIGc995EDkWEw8a82QwOEsq7Un-Es5Lnv4noYD7HjCX0HkxnLSMiqmdSdBePZ8kVtlBH0H8olCYJlQ-_652F_DGAIO2rl_6fY-dG6-v9iqImjRg-1wFzR6q_tk2RjkCXTFmnO_q6PBKQ0Eb4SFT77h7ri3NQ_qGUGOkjNrcI2HTnmGLlgFsuXmtbm9phahUNJG-9-TiIObSJK5zxQJDJn2tbbEserXp4acFBGYc103aO1NauerDt4ZNn1sHSQhHHTXYa7UuOERcr_DLAt1HOt_D7_ioRTozmW7vJdV3OIRm4S2SM83AMgSYw=Tzzqzc4reatgd4H_Lo=8Yx5ksBhgQFBNgEIndkek7N3U6NExsafQGx4J9JA-0HS1LD3cd4wi=QmLfLb"}}
```

Comment: What's your specific question about this? There is not a single way to decode such data. You can either try to decode it using the listed ways, or you need to ask whoever encoded it about more details

Comment: Also, "URL" is not any kind of encoding, neither is md5

Comment: Assuming I understand what you mean by _encoding_... In general, you cannot 'figure out' or infer text encoding. You must be told, or guess, and your guess may be wrong. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Whenever you see ```==``` at the end of a string, *(as of what I know)*  most of the times it will be **Base64**

Comment: I would like to decode this to see what is inserted in this json, I am testing a request

Comment: [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) you will find most of the things that you need

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this forum.  thanks Giorgos

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There is no **general** way to decode this.

Comment: I will take a look at this article thanks Nico

Comment: I just tried the ones I mentioned in the article because I don't know of other encoders, but I'm going to search about

Comment: Why not ask whoever encoded the data? Maybe it is not only encoded, but also encrypted, such that you need any key to decrypt it?

Comment: @NicoHaase Re.: *"URL" is not any kind of encoding* -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding : *Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding*

Comment: @jps while there can be any ways to encode characters such that they can be used in a URL, I would not call "URL" itself an encoding, compared to base64

Comment: @NicoHaase of course it's a bit sloppy to call URL "encoding",nonetheless URL-encoding is a form of encoding and quite commonly used and that's probably what the OP meant.